# Error where more hooks render than previous render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting this error `Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render` which to my knowledge I believe I am getting this because you can't call a hook inside a loop. My question is how do I not run that function in a loop here? Here is a snippet of where I am getting this error:

```
const getSomeData = (passedData: string): string | undefined => {
   const {
     data: someCoolDataReturned,
     error: someCoolDataReturnedError,
   } = useGetSomeCoolData(passedData);

   return someCoolDataReturned;
};



return (
    {mapThroughMe?.map(thing => (
       <div>{getSomeData(thing.description)}</div>
    ))}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You either need to have a hook that can handle multiple inputs and store an array of outputs/errors, or extract the inside part of the loop into a custom component.

If you can't change the code of the hook, then here's one way to get it to work:

```
const CoolDataRenderer = ({description}) => {
  const {data, error} = useGetSomeCoolData(thing.description);

  if (error) {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(error)}</div>;
  }

  return <div>{data}</div>;
}

// ... in whatever component you're in

return (
    {mapThroughMe?.map(thing => (
       <CoolDataRenderer key={thing.description} description={thing.description} />
    ))}
)
```

If `thing.description` is not unique, check if there's something unique such as `thing.id` so that you can properly use [keys](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key)